# Creating a array of extended types

Tags: go

I have a struct A, extending ("subclassing") it with struct B, like this:

```
package main

type A struct {
    x int
}

type B struct {
    A
    y int
}
```

I want to create a array where I can append A or B to it, so that this code works:

```
func main() {
    var m [2]B

    m[0] = B { A { 1 }, 2 }
    m[0].x = 0
    m[0].y = 0

    m[1] = A { 3 }
    m[1].x = 0
}
```

It doesn't. If I create the array of the type B, I get "cannot use struct literal (type A) as type B in assignment". If I try to create the array of the type A, I get the the same error (just with the types reversed).

So my question is: which type should the array be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `struct` values. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A struct {
    x int
}

type B struct {
    A
    y int
}

func main() {
    var m []interface{}
    m = append(m, B{A{1}, 2})
    m = append(m, A{3})
    fmt.Println(m[0], m[1])
    if b, ok := m[0].(B); ok {
        b.x = 0
        b.y = 0
        m[0] = b
    }
    if a, ok := m[1].(A); ok {
        a.x = 0
        m[1] = a
    }
    fmt.Println(m[0], m[1])
}

Output:
{{1} 2} {3}
{{0} 0} {0}
```

Or, you could use `struct` pointers. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A struct {
    x int
}

type B struct {
    A
    y int
}

func main() {
    var m []interface{}
    m = append(m, &B{A{1}, 2})
    m = append(m, &A{3})
    fmt.Println(m[0], m[1])
    if b, ok := m[0].(*B); ok {
        b.x = 0
        b.y = 0
    }
    if a, ok := m[1].(*A); ok {
        a.x = 0
    }
    fmt.Println(m[0], m[1])
}

Output:
&{{1} 2} &{3}
&{{0} 0} &{0}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you! I suppose my question now is: is this idiomatic? Am I doing in the "Go" way? I ask this because it seems a lot of code just to access the field of a "superstruct".

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to define the array type to `interface{}` rather than `B`. Then you can store both types in there. That's the only way to accomplish this. If both types implement a specific interface, then you can type to that instead of the generic `interface{}`

Comment: It doesn't work. Using `var m [2]interface{}` gets me    test.go:16: m[0].x undefined (type interface { } has no field or method x)  test.go:17: m[0].y undefined (type interface { } has no field or method y)  
test.go:20: m[1].x undefined (type interface { } has no field or method x)

Comment: You'll have to do a type cast when you pull it out, see here: http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Type_assertions

Comment: Then what'd be the correct syntax to change a field? I tried to replace `m[0].x = 0` for `m[0].(B).x = 0`, but now I get "cannot assign to m[0].(B).A.x".